# How to use JP3D in Openjpeg to compress medical images (. ni)

Tags: jpeg

I saw that Openjpeg-2.3.1 provides a JP3D method, and now I need to compress some medical images (. nii) through JP3D. First, I will download the source code of Openjpeg-2.3.1 and follow the tutorial on the official website

1. Mkdir build
2. CD build
3. Cmake G "Visual Studio 17 2022" - DCMAKE-BUILD-TYPE: string="Release" - DBUILD-SHARED-LIBS: bool=on - DBUILD_JP3D: bool=on - DCMAKE-INSTALL-PREFIX: path="% USERPROFILE%" - DCMAKE-LIBRARY-PATH: path="% USERPROFILE%" - DCMAKE-INCLUDE-PATH: path="% USERPROFILE% \ include"
   The generated OPENXPEG.sln needs to be compressed after generating a solution through Visual Studio. This is the command I used: e: \ OpenJPEG \ openjpeg 2.3.1 \ build \ bin \ Debug>opj_jp3d_compress - i output.bin - o output.jp3d - r 50. Then I saw that I needed to input three parameters: usage: jp3d_vm_enc - i bin volume file - m img file - o jp3d file (+options) https://github.com/uclouvain/openjpeg/tree/v2.3.1?tab=readme -OV file couldn't find any documentation on using JP3D, so I would like to ask about it
4. Regarding the - m img file section, an. img file needs to be passed in, but I converted. nii to. bin as input and did not have an. img file. What should I do
5. Is there any other way to compress. NII files through JP3D

Comment: How many bits per pixel?